# smtp / c# - how to set repy-to email address when using MimeMessage instance

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, sendgrid

The `MimeMessage.ReplyTo` property is readonly. How will I set value to this property?

Answer (score 0):

`MimeMessage.ReplyTo` has a method Add() which takes `MailboxAddress` as parameter. This add method can be used for this.